# Author does not maintain package anymore, what can i do?

Tags: react-native, package

I have come across this package https://github.com/januslo/react-native-sunmi-inner-printer
This package can only support react native version 0.61.3 and cannot support the latest version of react native.

I think the author does not maintain this package anymore. What can i do with it? I felt that i want to maintain it, but i am still new to programming.

Can anyone point me a way to maintain this package? I am worried that my apps will fail in the future if nobody maintain this package.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to contact the maintainer of the repo then I see these options:

- create a pull request for the repo and wait for approval
- ask for ownership or rights to become a project maintainer to merge the PR yourself
- fork the repo
- use `patch-package` to patch only locally your changes